# Why should \lst@definelanguage be preferred over \lstdefinelanguage in a style file?

Tags: listings, package-writing

The `listings` manual (v1.5b, subsection 4.18) recommends using `\lst@definelanguage` instead of `\lstdefinelanguage` in a style file:

> Where should I put my language definition? If you need the language
>   for one particular document, put it into the preamble of that
>   document. Otherwise create the local file `lstlang0.sty` or add the
>   definition to that file, but use `\lst@definelanguage` instead of
>   `\lstdefinelanguage`. [...]

However, I can't find a reason for this distinction between `\lst@definelanguage` and `\lstdefinelanguage` in either the manual or the developer guide. Is the distinction important?

You may be wondering why I'm asking this question... Well, I've managed to get everything working in my style file using `\lstdefinelanguage`. That said, I'd like to follow the guidelines laid out in the `listings` documentation as closely as possible.

However, if I simply substitute `\lst@definelanguage` for `\lstdefinelanguage`, I run into problems. Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

% --- generate the style file ---
\begin{filecontents*}{mystyle.sty}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{mystyle}

\DeclareOption*{\OptionNotUsed}  
\ProcessOptions\relax

\RequirePackage{listings}

\def\mylanguage{Mylanguage}
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\lstdefinelanguage%
\expandafter{\mylanguage}{keywords={foo}}

\endinput
\end{filecontents*}
% --- end of style file ---

\usepackage{mystyle}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Mylanguage]
foo bar baz
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Everything is hunky-dory with the code above, but if I simply replace `\lstdefinelanguage` by `\lst@definelanguage`, the `listings` packages throws two errors:

```
Couldn't load requested language.
```

and

```
language mylanguage undefined.
```

This seems to contradict the manual's claim that `\lstdefinelanguage` and `\lst@definelanguage` have the same syntax; at least, based on my simple test, they don't seem equivalent when in comes to expansion of their first argument.

Should I use `\lst@definelanguage` instead of `\lstdefinelanguage` and how can I get the former to work in my MWE?

Comment: Just to be clear: Your language is actually in a package file and this one you tried with `\usepackage{yourlang.sty}`?

Comment: @Speravir Correct. See my edit.

Comment: From what I have traced (and the manual says the same): `\lst@definelanguage` is meant to be used in _driver files only_. There are three existing ones: `lstlang1.sty`, `lstlang2.sty` and `lstlang3.sty`. One can have a local file `lstlang0.sty`. In such a file `\lst@definelanguage` works and should be used, `lstlang0.sty` would be used by `listings` automatically if available. For _all_ other use cases (which includes other packages) `\lstdefinelanguage` seems to be recommended. (I use the latter in my class for my package manuals).

Comment: (I lost track where the internals actually differ: it seems to have to do with how `aspects` are loaded...)

Comment: @cgnieder Thanks a lot for that. I had overlooked that discussion about the `lstlang0.sty` and friends in the developer guide. I had mistakenly assumed that, in the passage I quoted, `lstlang0.sty` was just a placeholder for some user `.sty` containing a language definition. You've comforted me in the thought that I can safely use `\lstdefinelanguage` in my style file. If you make that an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @cgnieder I guess the premise of the question is wrong, so maybe I should just delete it...

Comment: @Jubobs , if the manual recommends using `\lst@definelanguage`, it's just beyond me that you would not use `\lst@UserCommand\lst@definelanguage{\lst@DefLang\iftrue}`. instead.  Of course, we go back to point A, in which the author meant that it is preferable to use `lst@definelanguage` instead of `lstdefinelanguage`. Put it to a test, by replacing it to `\lst@UserCommand\lst@definelanguage{\lst@DefLang\iftrue}` test it out. It must be changed for the sake of reasoning. Whether you or I or cgnieder do not like it, it must be changed

Comment: @Jubobs isn't that what has been suggested since the beginning of TeX? Of course it's better to be safe. But if things are not working, they must be changed. If they collapse, then something else must be done about it.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it simply stems from a misinterpretation of the `listings` documentation.