# Lua syntax for the listings package

Tags: listings, lua

I'm preparing some slides with `Beamer` and I've just discovered that the `listings` package, which otherwise does exactly what I want, is missing the syntax for the `Lua` language. How can I configure `listings` to highlight Lua?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The premise of your question is wrong. The `listings` package defines no fewer than three Lua "dialects" in the file [`lstdvrs.dtx`](http://ftp.heanet.ie/pub/CTAN/tex/macros/latex/contrib/listings/lstdrvrs.dtx): `[5.0]Lua`, `[5.1]Lua`, and `[5.2]Lua`. Pick whichever is appropriate. You may want to change the way things look, but you shouldn't have to redefine all the syntax from scratch.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinestyle{myLuastyle}
{
  language         = {[5.0]Lua},
  basicstyle       = \ttfamily,
  showstringspaces = false,
  upquote          = true,
}

\lstset{style=myLuastyle}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
-- defines a factorial function
    function fact (n)
      if n == 0 then
        return 1
      else
        return n * fact(n-1)
      end
    end

    print("enter a number:")
    a = io.read("*number")        -- read a number
    print(fact(a))
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, effectively I was wrong. So the problem is elsewhere, your sample doesn't work for me, I must miss the file `lstdvrs.dtx`, I'm under Debian Wheezy with package `latex-beamer` installed, does this extension packaged, and do you know it's name ?

Comment: As far as I know, as long as your TeX distro comes with the `listings` package, you shouldn't have to worry about `lstdvrs.dtx`. All the necessary files should come with the package. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with Debian. Perhaps you should ask a separate question about that specific problem.

Comment: I found where the languages are defined, there are files under `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lang*.sty` there are a lot of language defined here but not `Lua`, I agree that the problem is more `Debian` related, so I'll look for a solution elsewhere, thanks again.

Comment: @Rodolphe: Looks like this should be of interest for you: [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092)

Answer (score 3):

There is dialect 5.0 defined:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings,inconsolata}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language={[5.0]Lua},basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,keywordstyle=\bfseries]
local words = io.open('hyphens-' .. tex.jobname .. '.txt', 'w');
local outchar = unicode.utf8.char
local function dumphyphens (head)
   local data = {}
   for v in node.traverse(head) do
       if v.id == node.id('glyph') then
         data[#data+1] = outchar(v.char);
       elseif v.id == node.id('disc') then
          data[#data+1] = '-'
       elseif v.id == node.id('glue') then
         data[#data+1] = outchar(32)
       elseif v.id == node.id('hlist') then
         data[#data+1] = dumphyphens(v.list)
       end
   end
   return table.concat(data)
end
callback.register ('hyphenate', function (head,tail)
   lang.hyphenate(head, tail) 
   words:write (dumphyphens(head) .. outchar(10))
   end)
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Don't use `\lst@definelanguage` here. Use `\lstdefinelanguage` instead; see [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160804/why-should-lstdefinelanguage-be-preferred-over-lstdefinelanguage-in-a-style-f). Also, if you want to use `*` as a keyword, you need to make it a letter first: `alsoletter=*`.

Comment: It makes _absolutely_ no difference!

Comment: Using `\lst@definelanguage` outside driver files can be associated with nasty side effects. See the question I link to and [cgnieder's comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160804/why-should-lstdefinelanguage-be-preferred-over-lstdefinelanguage-in-a-style-f#comment368008_160804).

Comment: The only difference is that `\lst@DefLang` is set to `\false`.